# Limit in multivariable-calculus

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $\ell$ be a straight line through origo. Determine the limit to the restriction of $$f(x,y)=xye^{-x^2y^2}$$ to $\ell$ when $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$. Also, investigate the limit $$\lim_{x^2+y^2 \to \infty} f(x,y). $$
How should I think about the restriction? As I understand it, we have a line $\ell(t) = kt, k \in \mathbb R$ and I want $f$ to follow this path which would give us $$f(t,kt) = \frac{tkt}{e^{t^2(kt)^2}} $$
and if either $t$ or $kt$ is fixed to its minimum value ($0$) we get, by letting the other variable approach $\infty$, 
$$\lim_{t^2 \to \infty} f(t,0) = \frac{t \cdot 0}{e^{t^2(0)^2}} =0 $$
and
$$\lim_{(kt)^2 \to \infty} f(0,kt) = \frac{0 \cdot kt}{e^{0^2(kt)^2}} = 0$$ 
and so the limit should be equal to 0. Is this correct? And how do I "realize" that the second limit doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some misunderstanding. It is correct that you fixed a line $y = kx$ (that is, $k$ is the slope of the line), and then you let $x \to \infty$ (So by that equation, $y \to \infty$ also).

Now you have

$$f(x, kx) = \frac{xkx}{e^{x^2 k^2x^2}} = \frac{kx^2}{e^{k^2 x^4}}$$

So there are two case:

- $k=0$: Then $f(x, 0)  =0$ for all $x$ and so $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x, 0) = 0$.
- $k\neq 0$: The bottom is growing much faster than the top, so $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x, kx) = 0$

As a result, when restricted to all $\ell$ of the form $\{y = kx\}$, we have

$$(*)\ \ \ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x, kx) = 0.$$

**However**, this (*) is not the same as saying that

$$\lim_{x^2 +y^2 \to \infty} f(x, y) = 0$$

Indeed, this is not true: Consider another curve $y = \frac{1}{x}$. Then

$$f(x, \frac{1}{x}) = e^{-1}$$

for all $x$. So $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x, \frac{1}{x}) = e^{-1}\neq 0$. This shows that the limit

$$\lim_{x^2 +y^2 \to \infty} f(x, y) $$

does not exist.

Comment: But the answer sheet says that the limit to the restriction $$f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{e^{x^2y^2}}$$ of $\ell$ is $0$ when $x^2+y^2 \to \infty$. I don't understand how I should interpret the limit to the restriction of $\ell$.

Comment: Ar you are right. I made some computational mistake. PLease see my edit (soon) @Lozansky

Comment: @Lozansky: The post is edited.

Comment: This is incorrect, $f(x,y) \neq \frac{x}{e^{x^2}} \frac{y}{e^{y^2}} $. I am supposed to show that $\lim_{x^2+y^2} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right. See the edit again.

Comment: Thank you, may I ask how the curve $y=1/x$ came to mind, i.e. what was your reasoning to try that curve specifically?

Comment: Cause there's a $xy$ term (both at top and bottom). So setting $xy = $constant would give me something.

Answer (score 1):

Note that along $y=1/x,x>0, f(x,y) = e^{-1}.$ So as $x^2 + y^2 \to \infty $ along this curve, $f(x,y) \not \to 0.$ Since we know that $f \to 0$ on lines through the origin, this shows that $\lim_{x^2+y^2\to \infty}f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Comment: I would like to ask you the same question as I asked John; how did the curve $y=1/x$ come to your mind? What specific quality about $f(x,y)$ led you to try that curve?

Comment: It occurred to me that we have $(xy)e^{-(xy)^2}.$ What if $xy$ is a constant? That's a pretty natural question at that point. So I just said, OK, try $xy = 1.$

Comment: Aren't we restricting $f$ to a straight line?

Comment: In the first part yes, in the second part no.